# iOS: Animation Not working in observeValueForKeyPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, key-value-observing

I used KVO to [observe changes in a frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19687115/1356559) and set another frame accordingly

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:KeyPathForFrameBeingObserved]) {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            CGRect frame = [self playWithFrame:viewBeingMonitored.frame];
            self.viewToAnimate.frame = frame;
         }];
    }
}
```

Code in the animation block is executed but animation is not working, I suspected that repeated calls to animation method could cause this but using log messages I found that animation is not working even for a single call, can anyone explain that ?

iPad 2/(iOS8.4)

- I have tried including the animation method call in  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... });` but animation still not working.
- I have tried pushing the observed changes in queue and delaying the animation method for a second using `dispatch_after` to run it only using the last element in the queue to avoid repeated calls but didn't work.
- KVO is working perfectly (adding the observer is already handled), but the code in the animation block is executed without animation.

Comment: did you call addObserver forKeyPath in your object ?

Comment: @Coyote Yes, I did, KVO is working perfectly but the result is not animated.

Comment: Does this thread apply at all?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277109/uiview-animatewithduration-not-animating-in-ios8

Comment: Yeah the answerer in that question recommended modifying the auto layout constraints (the constant property), instead of modifying the frame (as you are doing in the code you posted)

Comment: is **presentationLayer** the issue?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582192/ios-observing-change-in-frame-of-a-uiview-during-animation

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to observe the property of an UIKit object.  Keep in mind that:

> ... the classes of the UIKit framework generally do not support KVO ...

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html

So, you have to check if your `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` is calling in fact.

Comment: KVO already worked in my case, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19687115/1356559 , the problem is that code in the animation blocks is executed but without animation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question but I thought I would answer in case someone else is reading this. You will need to call setFrame to set the frame of the animation instead of the simple assignment.

CGRect frame = [self playWithFrame:viewBeingMonitored.frame];
[self.viewToAnimate setFrame:frame];